# Redirecting to a different context url from Controller in Spring MVC 2.5

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

From the controller I have to redirect to a different `ServletContext` using

`ModelAndView` object.The  current servletcontext is /user , but I have to

redirect to /man.

I tried to redirect using

```
return  new ModelAndView("redirect:/man/dashboard.htm", map);
```

This didnt work out, just appended to current context like /user/man/dashboard.htm

So I tried with

```
return  new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(request.getContextPath()+"/man/Dashboard.htm", false), map);
```

This worked, but I am not sure whether this a good approach or not.

or any other possibilities?

Comment: Just do: `return  new ModelAndView("redirect:man/dashboard.htm", map);" without the slash

Comment: No, this just appends like /user/man/dashboard.htm